# "I'm tired of she keeps bugging me" or "I'm tired of her bugging me"?

Tags: grammar

> I'm tired of **she keeps bugging me!**

I've been googling about this (found nothing) and I feel stupid but I think the grammar above is not right. What's the correct way?

Is this better?

> I'm tired of **her bugging me!**

Comment: *I'm tired because she keeps bugging me.  I'm tired of her always bugging me.*

Comment: @Anonym your comment arrived as soon as my edit. So, what is this clause called?

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Comment: You can say : I'm tired of her bugging me or I am tired of being bugged by her all the time.

Comment: @Kris I forgot that site exists.. thanks, if someone could migrate this question there that'd be great

Comment: In what context did you find this? That might (possibly) make a difference.

Comment: @ClickRick It's just regular sentence I found that I suspected has a wrong grammar. So, it depends on the context too?

Comments above have already answered my question but if anyone wants to give proper answer and a little explanation, I'll accept.

Comment: @Zyoo It is not "correct" in English, as previous commenters have said, but if it had occurred in a poetic or literary context then the style could have been conveying something about the speaker. An alternative thought is to consider the native language of the person who said it - it might be a literal translation of the words which could be valid in their language.

Comment: Can we keep this question open?  It seems like a good learner's question about complementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's specific example falls somewhere between "dialectal" and "ungrammatical". I suspect many native speakers would go for the second of those classifications, but this might well be because ***keep/keeps***.

Very often when you say you're *tired of [something]*, you're speaking to the person who's actually doing the thing that's [*getting on your nerves*](http://www.idiomeanings.com/idioms/get-on-ones-nerves/). Most of us are used to hearing *both* these constructions...

> 1: *"I'm [sick and] tired of **you** complaining!"*
>    2: *"I'm [sick and] tired of **your** complaining!"*

I've no reason to complain about the grammaticality of either of those. Feasibly, some "purists" might think only #2 is "correct", but I think that's a pedantic position. Notice that if we switch to third person singular *masculine*, we get 1a: ***him*** complaining, 2a: ***his*** complaining, but third person singular *feminine* is ***her*** complaining in both cases (so exactly how we parse it is inherently ambiguous).

But things get decidedly awkward when we introduce the "verb" ***keep***. My scare quotes are because in the current context I find the usage almost indistinguishable from the *adverbial* alternative ***always***. Probably most native speakers would accept at least one of my first two examples as "valid", but at some point in the following list, they'd start rejecting similar usages (for no obvious reason)...

> 3: *"I'm tired of you always complaining!"*
>    4: *"I'm tired of your always complaining!"*
>    5: *"I'm tired of you keep complaining!"*
>    6: *"I'm tired of your keep complaining!"*

Comment: Exactly this. After discussion in the comment, my subconscious was still a little bit confused about when to use **him/me** or **his/my**. And my using "keep" was actually accidental yet opens another discussion. Thank u.

Comment: "I'm tired of your constant complaining"...would also sound fine to my ears though.

Comment: Or even "I'm tired of the way you keep complaining" would also sound fine.

Comment: @Tim: It's true everyone would accept *constant* with the possessive pronoun, but I think *no-one* would accept *"I'm tired of you constant complaining"*. The only written instance I can easily find for my *keep* example with a non-possessive pronoun is the Rolling Stones [*"I'm sick and tired of **you** keep chasing me"*](http://www.keno.org/stones_lyrics/leave%20_me_alone.htm). It might not be a common usage, but it *does* occur (particularly in BrE, I suspect). Introducing ***the way*** is only possible with the simple pronoun ***you***, so would not suit my purpose in examples 3-6 above.